# How can I edit a readonly file?

Tags: files, read-only

We have no privileges to change file permissions. We have no permissions even for super users. How can we edit this file?

Comment: @dsstorefile and how do they put edited file back in place ?

Comment: What is your real goal? You might be getting an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: That is the purpose of permissions, to prevent unauthorized users to read/write/execute.
Only solution that I see is possible is to boot the system from USB drive and to edit that file. But if the file/drive is encrypted there is no way you can do it.

Answer (score 3):

As [pointed out by dsstorefile](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028300/how-can-i-edit-a-readonly-file#comment1671877_1028300), you can copy the contents of the file to another file for which you have writing rights, and then edit the writable file.

Then you can put the edited file back in place by deleting the original file and copying your new file at the same place.

In more detail:

### Using command-line / terminal

#### If you can create files in the directory where your file is

If the original read-only file is called `original.csv`
and you want your writable file to be called `data.csv`, you can open a terminal, go to the directory where your file is, and run the command:

```
cat original.csv > data.csv
```

and now you can open and edit the `data.csv` file.

Once the editing is done,

```
rm original.csv
```

When asked if you want to delete the read-only file, answer `y`

```
mv data.csv original.csv
```

#### If your file is in a directory you cannot write to

If `/path/to/writable/dir/` is the name of a directory you can write to, if the original read-only file is called `original.csv`
and if you want your writable file to be called `data.csv`, you can open a terminal, go to the directory where your file is, and run the command:

```
cat original.csv > /path/to/writable/dir/data.csv
```

and now you can open and edit the `data.csv` file in `/path/to/writable/dir/`. In this situation, you won't be able to put your modified file where the original file was.

### Without using terminal

- Open your csv with a text editor, for example *gedit* .
- Copy all the content of the file, for example with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- Create a new file within the editor
- Paste the contents of the csv, for example with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
- Save your new file with a name that ends with `.csv`
- delete the original file
- move the edited file where the original file was, and rename it if necessary

Comment: What are the reasons for using `cat` (main purpose: con**cat**enation of files) instead of `cp` (copy command)?

Comment: cp will preserve the rights, so the result will be read-only as well.
cat will create a new file, with the default rights; so a file you can write to, in most cases

Comment: _“cp will preserve the rights”_ There are parameters to control this but I agree, `cat` could be simpler. (Even when compared with editors as suggested by @dsstorefile.)

Comment: Indeed, you can change the behaviour of cp, for example with the --no-preserve option. I wasn't aware of it; thank you :)

Comment: If you can write on the directory a file is in, you can always force write on the file anyway, (as dsstorefile1 noted in a comment on this answer) so there's no need to move or copy it. If you can't write on the directory, you need root. But, OP's question, which is quite unclear, seems to me to imply not that they don't have root but that even root has no permission, meaning the problem is that the filesystem is mounted read only and cannot be written to except possibly by re-mounting rw, (which may fail or be unsafe in various circumstances, such as when it's a hibernated NTFS partition).